# Deal with document type data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, nosql

So I processed a lot of logs data and at the end I get lines with various lengths for each type of logs.

For example I will get :

> ("WARNING","06","05","2017","09","15","Certs problem","Wrong SSL")
>
> ("ERROR","06","05","2017","09","15","403","Not Enough
>   Bandwidth","Paris","48.15","55.16")
>
> ("INFO","06","05","2017","09","15","User connected")

But for one type of logs, they will always have the same structure and length. So what do I have to do ?

Should I create a Spark DF for each type of logs ? (not good for me, cuz i need to cross the logs for analytics)

Should I go with NoSQL approach ? All the mutual fields as the date, the hour, etc.. plus an array infos at the end corresponding to each type of logs infos. IF this, how can I do it in Spark ? The Spark DF API doesn't allow this, right ? Warning and errors logs would become this as Spark DF rows :

> ("WARNING","06","05","2017","09","15",["Certs problem","Wrong SSL"])
>   ("ERROR","06","05","2017","09","15",["403","Not Enough
>   Bandwidth","Paris","48.15","55.16"])

Finally should I just create a lot of variables in a Spark DF ? Like all the mutual columns plus **warn_desc1, warn_desc2, error_desc1, error_desc2, error_desc3, error_desc4, error_desc5, info_desc1** ? That would imply a lot of null values, I mean for the rows of *Errors*, all the fields corresponding to *Warnings* and *Infos* would be null ! Is that a good approach ? An example :

> ("ERROR","06","05","2017","09","15",**null**,**null**,"403","Not Enough
>   Bandwidth","Paris","48.15","55.16",**null**)

What would you do ? I wanna see what's the Spark philosophy for this problem type ! Are all approaches okayish ? Or Are there some to banned of my mind ?

Thanks a lot for help, have a good week end !

Tricky :^)

Comment: All these log types are in a single file ?

Comment: Yes ! 250Gb of data per day ! :p

Comment: great !! Which Spark version you are using ?

Comment: I will suggests to create a single dataframe and define schema based on the line which has highest record and register a temporary table from it. In this case you will get null records for others but you can deal with it in further processing.

Comment: 250Gb of logs in one file is a bad practice. Spark will spend most of his time partitioning data before progressing it.

Comment: It's not in one file ahahhaha, it was just an indicator of how much data I deal with. I have many many .logs files !